# CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on null in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, overriding

I got error "CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on null in sale-flash.php in Woocommerce". Can Anyone help me to resolve this issue? Here is my store url: https://jalaj.aphroecs.com/newbooboo/shop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store URL doesn't help in that case.

> It seems related to a Woocommerce template overrides in your theme that is outdated.

You should check in Woocommerce > Status at the end of the page in "Template Overrides" section at the end, to see if there is some outdated Woocommerce templates in your theme (in red).

If it is the case, you will need to update your theme, or to replace the corresponding template file, copying it:

- from Woocommerce plugin > templates > single-product > sale-flash.php
- To your active theme > woocommerce > single-product > sale-flash.php

This should solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec,  I have checked and update all pages but still coming that error

Comment: @JalajKumar have you rechecked in Woocommerce > Status at the end of the page in "Template Overrides" section

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I have updated all woocommerce template files. all looks green now but still same error. If possible can you help me on personal chat?